# What exactly is edge density?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing

I'm kinda confuse of the meaning of edge density. From the equation,

```
edge density = sum(x=1,w) sum(y=1,h) e(x,y)/N
```

where e is the edge map image (magnitude of vertical edge at (x,y)), there are two version of N.
1st version - N = w x h (width x height)
2nd version - N = number of non zero vertical edge pixel

What I don't understand is how can I calculate the edge density? Is it just summation of the white edges pixels?

**Edited**

Hi all, from what I understand from reading the paper given by @Gilgamesh, the N is the area of the region, width times its height but from the answer given it seems there is a conflict whereby N refers to number of non white pixels(black pixel). So, which is the correct one? Here is another reference on the N value [calculating edge density](http://www.google.com.my/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://digital.liby.waikato.ac.nz/conferences/ivcnz07/papers/ivcnz07-paper42.pdf&ei=jhFNUcH_DJGIrAeH-oBI&usg=AFQjCNEM3r1UfPTFiBGPfWGi_w-Wy0F8pg&bvm=bv.44158598,d.bmk).

Comment: This **is** a real question. A technical, specific one, but still valid, in my opinion.

Comment: ohh ok. Am I asking in the wrong place?

Comment: I think it is the good place, but not everyone seem to share my opinion. This is why I wrote the comment.

Answer (score 2):

basically the edge density is really just a (local) average density, which you can either calculate over binarized images or, more common, over grey scale images.

And yes, it is basically just summing up over both x and y coordinates in a subimage in most cases, see equation (1) here

http://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1517&context=infopapers

and averaging afterwards.

Regards,
G.

Comment: @Gilgamesh Thanks for sharing. But what does it mean by "measures the
average edge magnitude"? Do we need to compute integral image in order to calculate the it? If i'm not mistaken from integral image we could find the mean and standard deviation. Does average of edge refers to the mean?

Comment: Hoi. I hope I can explain it well enough :-) You can either detect edges and label them or, easier most times, extract edges via Canny, Sobel or alike and binarize using a threshold. In the latter case, no labeling is needed and you can, as you mentioned yourself, just use the integral image and normalize by the number of nonzero pixels. Hope that helps, G.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand about edge density, it is defined as [image: formula] where [image: W] are the white pixels and [image: N] is the total number of pixels i.e. [image: widthxheight].

[image: N] cannot be the number of black pixels because the number could be arbitrary, ranging from zero to all pixels and the range of edge density will then be [image: zti].

When [image: N] is the area, the range will be [image: zto] which portrays just what we want, the places where edges are dense (or sparse depending on your requirement).

Answer (score 0):

The edge map is the map of gradient magnitude (i.e. the length of the gradient vector). So the edge density is the average of the gradient magnitude over a neighborhood.
If you have a binary edge map where 0 means no-edge, 1 means edge (this can be obtained by thresholding the gradient magnitude), then the edge density is just the ratio of edge/non-edge pixels.

Comment: From what I understand about what you wrote. 1st:average of the gradient magnitude over a neighborhood == mean == edge density? 2nd:edge/non-edge == use connected component analysis on the edge map to find the number of object(edges)/(wxh-countNonZero(I))?Sorry but I'm quite confusing.